# How to convert csv file to bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, conversion, tools, csv

I have a csv file of the database Springer as follows:

**Columns**

```
Item Title,Publication Title,Book Series Title,Journal Volume,Journal Issue,Item DOI,Authors,Publication Year,URL,Content Type
```

**Data of each column**

```
"Architectural Requirements for Cloud Computing Systems: An Enterprise Cloud Approach","Journal of Grid Computing","","9","1","10.1007/s10723-010-9171-y","Bhaskar Prasad RimalAdmela JukanDimitrios KatsarosYves Goeleven","2011","http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10723-010-9171-y","Article"
"Cloud Computing Evolution","Cloud Computing Basics","","","","10.1007/978-1-4614-7699-3_1","S. Srinivasan","2014","http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-7699-3_1","Chapter"
"Testing-as-a-Service for Mobile Applications: State-of-the-Art Survey","Dependability Problems of Complex Information Systems","","","","10.1007/978-3-319-08964-5_4","Oleksii StarovSergiy VilkomirAnatoliy GorbenkoVyacheslav Kharchenko","2015","http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-08964-5_4","Chapter"
"Cloud Computing in Agriculture","Agricultural Bioinformatics","","","","10.1007/978-81-322-1880-7_12","L. N. Chavali","2014","http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-81-322-1880-7_12","Chapter"
"The Role of Cloud Computing Architecture in Big Data","Information Granularity, Big Data, and Computational Intelligence","","","","10.1007/978-3-319-08254-7_13","Mehdi BahramiMukesh Singhal","2015","http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-08254-7_13","Chapter"
"An Implementation of Automatic Software Testing on Cloud Computing Environment","Computer Science and its Applications","","","","10.1007/978-3-662-45402-2_176","Chorng-Shiuh KoongTzu-I YangChang-Chung Wu","2015","http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-45402-2_176","Chapter"
```

How do I convert a file in csv format to bibtex? Is there any solution for Linux?

Comment: Open it on your favourite spreadsheet application, then add columns  before/after each field like  `title={` and `}, journal={`,etc. Be sure that the last colum is `}}`. The make a first column with   `@article{`  and  a second column with a  keyword and a comma like `Bhaskar2011`. This can be done automatically with a formula  like `=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",G1)-1) & H1 & ", "`. Then select all the cells and paste it in a text editor. Save it with the `.bib` extension. Finally open yourfile.bib with JabRef to test if there are some errors.

Comment: This is really not a TeX question: as @Fran says this is something to do using a text editor.

Comment: In addition to @Fran's answer: using e.g. the char(13) (Excel) function you can even add linebreaks to the resulting bibtex code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help of all of you @Fran, Joseph Wright and Uwe Ziegenhagen, will surely help me a lot.

Comment: https://www.freefileconvert.com/csv-bib